# Is there a Bezout's theorem for holomorphic functions of two variables?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Is there an analogue of the Bezout's Theorem which pertains to holomorphic functions of two variables defined on a fixed domain or germs of analytic functions of more than one variable at $0$?

I have never seen a proof nor have I seen a counter-example.

Edit: More concretely, if we consider the ring of germs of analytic functions in several variables at $0$, is it true that for two such germs having no common factors, the set of their common zeros is discrete?

Comment: Isnt this just bezout's theorem focused on a small open subset of $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$, so we just have the inequality where the sum of multiplicities is $\leq$ the product of degrees?

Comment: I mean $\mathbb{P}^n _{\mathbb{C}}, n > 1$.

Comment: @basket I am sorry, but I don't know about Bezout's Theorem for $\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$. I only know about the Bezout's Theorem for polynomials. Does it say something about holomorphic functions of several variables also?

Comment: I'm sorry you're right, somehow I conflated holomorphic and rational